# Export release key while using shared crosswalk platform in android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, release, crosswalk-runtime

i am using x_walk_view as its web view in shared mode platform for android version 4.4 and below version.It works fine but when i try to export in a release mode,It starts giving error "YOUR APP STOPPED WORKING".does i have to enable something to use crosswalk ?
I am new to this crosswalk platform please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay i got it after some days,crosswalk library with proguard enabled causes the error.I just disabled crosswalk library in pro-guard then exported,Now working like a charm